# Java communication with CMMO-ST-C5-1-LKP Festo controller over MODBUS TCP/IP

Tags: java, modbus-tcp

I have an assignment to develop a Java library for communication with a CMMO-ST-C5-1-LKP Festo controller. 
I have read the controller documentation and it provides a MODBUS TCP/IP communication interface. I have used jamod and managed to connect to the controller. (I have configured and parametrised the axis)
The problem is that I don't really understand the communication encoding (what bytes do I need to send to get the axis to move somewhere). I have tried to find some example of the communication (bytes beeing send and recived), but I can't find any.

Does anyone know where I might find an example of communication?

Sorry, if this question is out of place here. I am completly stuck.

Answer (score 1):

here - https://www.festo.com/net/cs_cz/SupportPortal/default.aspx?cat=4561&q=CMMO-ST&tab=4&s=t#result is many examples from other controllers (not PC, PLC only) maby you can find any inspiration.
Good  tool for commissioning of CMMO drive is Modbus TCP simulator - https://www.festo.com/net/cs_cz/SupportPortal/default.aspx?q=modbus&tab=4

If you set a stop, halt, OPM1, digital input - enable - short PAUSE - enable.
If enable (output) output is set, you should be able to start reference move - hom. after homing (ideály set current position for start in FCT) you can set a speed and position to move and set start.

Good luck

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please keep in mind that answers should be more or less self-contained, and when you include links, they should generally be in english. Try to summarize the gist of the linked content in the post, so that if the link ever gets outdated, there's still most of the answer left